# Selecting array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the following array:

```
$ISBN = '0,1,9,8,5,x,8,0,3,0';

$inArray = explode(',',$ISBN);
```

While this loop prints the numbers 10-1 like so `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`:

```
for($i=10; $i>0; $i=$i-1)
{
    echo $i." ";
}
```

I want to multiply each element accordingly starting from the first one. For example: `10*inArray[0] + 9*inArray[1] + 8*inArray[2]` and when it hits `x` to print it like `6*x` for example; etc.

Comment: We can't write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$factor = count($inArray);
foreach($inArray as &$value) {
    if($value != "x") {
       $value *= $factor;
    } else {
       $value = $factor.'*'.$value; 
    }
    $factor--;
}
unset($value);
```

Value of `$inArray` would be:

```
0,9,72,56,30,5*x,32,0,6,0
```

Comment: Yeah that does it. Thanks for your time, will accept the answer ASAP :)